# Docusign RestAPI navigate to last page

Tags: docusignapi

We have used RestAPI method for sending invitation to signers. When signers clcik on View Documnent link in email they should be navigated to the last page of the document.

Is there any feature for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to navigate to the last page for users.  Users can do it themselves by clicking "Next" button that will take them to the next actionable item.

Comment: Agreed- if you only have a tab on the last page of the document and you want your users to go directly there then if they open the envelope and hit next or begin signing they will be automatically scrolled to the last page where the tab is.  If they don't, check your Preferences -> Features page and there's an option to auto-scroll...